# Providing a stable url to access a docker container from another docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We are using `docker-compose` to bring up multiple containers and link them together.

We need to be able to persist the url of a service running in **containerA** in our data store so that we can look it up at a later date and use it to access the service from **containerB**. **containerB** should not have to know whether the service is running as a local container or not, it should just be able to grab the url and use it.

We can get the address of a linked container using envoronment variables in the standard way eg

`http://$CONTAINER_A_SERVICE_PORT_9000_TCP_ADDR:$CONTAINER_A_SERVICE_PORT_9000_TCP_PORT/someresource`

but my understanding is that if we store this url and try to access the service after restarting the containers, docker may have assigned a new port and/or ip to the container and the address could be invlaid.

At the moment all I can think of is exposing the port of the container on the host machine and using the public address of the host as the stable endpoint to the container but I would really like a solution that avoided going out to the public network.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would use the hostname of serviceB that gets put into `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Thanks! that will work providing that i don't change my container linking names/aliases. Pretty much exactly what I need. If you put your comment in the form of answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the hostname of serviceB that gets put into `/etc/hosts`